# PHP MySQLi Wrapper Class For API

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've never had my code reviewed before, so I am taking this opportunity to see what can be improved with my coding style. I am still somewhat "new" to PHP, in the sense that I'm an old dog finally learning new tricks.

Here is a MySQLi wrapper I've coded in PHP. Overall, this code is part of an API project. I'm making an API in PHP which I will use for my WPF Desktop Application for the Database Models.

Here is `Class.Config.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Database;

use Exceptions\DatabaseException;
use Exceptions\ConnectionException;

class Config
{
    /**
    * @var string $host The connection host.
    * @var string $username The connection username.
    * @var string $password The connection password.
    * @var string $dbname The connection database name.
    */
    private string $host, $username, $password, $dbname;

    /**
    * @var \mysqli $conn The mysqli connection object.
    */
    private \mysqli $conn;

    /**
    * Configures the Config object with the default connection string.
    *
    * @param array $config The config array, expects indexes of: host, username, password, and dbname.
    * @param mysqli $connection The optional mysqli connection object.
    */
    public function __construct(?array $config = null, \mysqli $connection = null)
    {
        if ($connection !== null && !($connection instanceof \mysqli))
        {
          throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            "Invalid mysqli connection object passed. Instance of 'mysqli' expected, '" . gettype($connection) . "' given."
          );
        }

        if ($config === null)
        {
            // Retrieve an array of the connection data from the database.ini file.
            $config = parse_ini_file("database.ini");
        }

        // Retrieve the database credentials from the parsed file
        foreach($config as $key => $value)
        {
          $this->$key = $value ?? null;
        }

        // Verify that the config file properly sets up the variables.
        try
        {
            if (!isset($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname)
                || empty($this->host)
                || empty($this->username)
                || empty($this->password)
                || empty($this->dbname))
            {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Connection string expects values for ['host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname']");
            }
        }
        catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e)
        {
            error_log("Missing Configuration Index: {$e}");
            throw $e;
        }

        // Create a new MySQLi connection
        $this->conn =
            $connection ??
            new \mysqli(
                $this->host,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->dbname
            );
    }

    /**
    * Validates the connection.
    *
    * @return mysqli The mysqli connection object.
    */
    public function connect()
    {
        try
        {
            /**
            * Checks to see if there are any errors with the validated connection string.
            *
            * @var \mysqli $this->conn The connection object configured in the constructor.
            */
            if ($this->conn->connect_error)
            {
                throw new ConnectionException(
                  $this->conn->connect_error
                );
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->conn;
            }
        }
        catch (ConnectionException $e)
        {
            error_log("Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
        catch (DatabaseException $e)
        {
            error_log("Database Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            error_log("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here is `class.MySQLi.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Database;

use Database\Config;

class MySQLi
{

  /**
  * @var \mysqli $conn The mysqli connection object.
  */
  private \mysqli $conn;

  /**
  * Initialize the connection between the database config.
  */
  public function __construct()
  {
      $conn = new Config;
      $this->conn = $conn->connect();
  }

  /**
  * Method for getting the connection variable.
  *
  * @return \mysqli | bool $this->conn The mysqli object configured in the constructor.
  */
  public function getConnection() : \mysqli | bool
  {
    return $this->conn;
  }

  /**
  * Close the connection once the script ends.
  */
  public function __destruct()
  {
      $this->conn->close();
  }

  /**
  * Build a parameterized query to protect against SQL injections by default.
  *
  * @param string $query The SQL query string with placeholders for parameters.
  * @param mixed ...$params The array? of parameters to be bound to the query.
  * @return \mysqli_result|bool Returns the result of the query or false if an error is encountered.
  */
  public function Query(string $query, ...$params) : \mysqli_result | bool
  {
      // Prepare the SQL statement or trigger an error if preparation fails.
      $statement = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query) or trigger_error($this->getConnection()->error, E_USER_ERROR);

      if (!$statement) return false;

      // Build the parameters if provided.
      if(!empty($params))
      {
          $types = [];
          $bindParams = [];

          foreach ($params as $param)
          {
              // Get the type of each parameter: i, d, s, or b.
              $types[] = $this->getParamType($param);
              $bindParams[] = $param;
          }

          try
          {
              $types = implode("", $types);
              $statement->bind_param($types, ...$bindParams);
          }
          catch (\ArgumentCountError $e)
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      // Execute the statement and return the result if successful
      if ($statement->execute())
      {
          $result = $statement->get_result();
          $statement->close();
          return $result;
      }

      return false;
  }

  /**
  * Insert rows of data into a database table.
  *
  * @param string $query The SQL query string with placeholders for parameters.
  * @param mixed ...$params The array? of parameters to be bound to the query.
  */
  public function Insert(string $query, ...$params)
  {
  // Still debating usage.
  }

  /**
  * Fetch rows of data from a database table.
  *
  * @param string $query The SQL query string with placeholders for parameters.
  * @param mixed ...$params The array? of parameters to be bound to the query.
  * @return array|false Returns an array of rows on success, or false on failure.
  */
  public function Rows(string $query, ...$params) : array | bool
  {
    if($result = $this->Query($query, ...$params))
    {
        $rows = [];

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        return $rows;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
 * Get the parameter type for binding in a prepared statement.
 *
 * @param mixed $param The parameter value.
 * @return string Returns the parameter type character.
 */
  private function getParamType($param) : string
  {
      if (is_int($param))
      {
          return "i";
      }
      elseif (is_float($param))
      {
          return "d";
      }
      elseif (is_string($param))
      {
          return "s";
      }
      else
      {
          return "b";
      }
  }
}
?>
```

## Usage

### Simplify Fetching Rows From Database

With my wrapper class, I can simply do this:

```
// Get the database connection
$conn = new MySQLi;

// SQL query to select all data from the table
$query = "SELECT * FROM structure_ranks";

// Fetch all rows from the result set and store them in the array
$rows = $conn->Rows($query);

// Output the array as JSON
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

As opposed to doing this:

```
// Create an instance of the Config class
$config = new Config();

// Get the database connection
$conn = $config->connect();

// Check the connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// SQL query to select all data from the table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM structure_ranks";

// Execute the query
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Fetch all rows from the result set and store them in the array
$array = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
}

// Close the connection
$conn->close();

// Output the array as JSON
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! There is a [tag:beginner] tag which could be added, if you so choose.

Comment: Just a small remark. I was reading your code and came accross a `$conn` variable in several places. In your code `$conn` can be an instantiation of the `mysqli` class, or an instantiation of the `Config` class. So, what does "conn" really mean? Oh, and you also have a `$connection` variable. I'm confused. I think it is good practice when a variable name uniquely describes what it contains. Same is true for class names. Your `Config` class actually makes the database connection and your `MySQLi` class queries it. Those were the best names you could come up with?

Comment: My point is that naming things properly makes your code easier to read. Readability is more important than shorter code. If a variable name needs 10 characters instead of 5 to be comprehensible and unique, then so be it. Good code starts with choosing good names.

Comment: In all use cases, that `$conn` variable returns this: `// Create a new MySQLi connection $this->conn = $connection ?? new \mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);`, which is from the constructor of the Config class. So, `$conn = new Config;` just means `$conn = new mysqli(...)` The config class could've been called something else, but it just sets up and validates the mysqli connection. That one of `connection` variable was my attempt to say "this connection variable is from the outside, different from everything else going on here"

Comment: I'm sorry to be stubborn, but `$conn = new Config();` isn't the same as `$conn = new mysqli()` or even `$conn = new MySQLi()`. The confusion seems real. Anyway, all I wanted to say is that your "naming of things" needs some work, the details are less important. Here's a bit of a [backgrounder](https://makimo.pl/blog/scientific-perspective-on-naming-in-programming/). Just think what will happen when you need to configure something else? Will you use class `Config2`?

Comment: Well, that is why we have namespaces right? Database\Config, I can't imagine anything else that would need to be Configured with the Database that can't be done in that class. But you are right that `$conn = new Config();` was the wrong move. Oversight since it's only purpose is expose the `connect()` method, which returns the true connection. I will change that line of code

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a lot of issues and possible improvements. For example, the entire Config class being one big pile of useless cargo cult code that you wrote not because it is really needed but just to try your hand at those "new tricks". Just one quick example. The following condition will *never* be evaluated to `true`, being essentially useless:

```
if ($connection !== null && !($connection instanceof \mysqli))
```

simply because one line above you already asked PHP to check the $mysqli variable type and throw exception in case it's incorrect:

```
public function __construct(?array $config = null, \mysqli $connection = null)
```

Here you can see a [live demonstration](https://3v4l.org/ukkMu). You are expecting this code to throw `\InvalidArgumentException` with custom error message in case `$mysqli` is not `null` and not `mysqli`. But, as you can see, it's another error, which is thrown even before the execution reached that condition.

And it's the case with almost every other exception thrown in your code.

Yet I am not sure whether you are inclined to listen (or even still have any interest in a review at all). So I would rather concentrate on the false assumptions that led you to the creation of these two rather monstrous classes.

The "As opposed to doing this", being rewritten using the correct approach and the most recent PHP version, should be read as

```
// get the configuration options
$config = require 'config.php';

// Get the database connection
$conn = new mysqli(...$config['db']);

// SQL query to select all data from the table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM structure_ranks";

// Fetch all rows from the result set and store them in the array
$result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Output the array as JSON
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you have any questions regarding the code present or not present in this example, feel free to ask in the comments or you may help yourself to the [short article on mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) I wrote.

As you can see, when used properly, mysqli is already as concise as your custom solution. And even with prepared statements:

```
// SQL query using a variable
$sql = "SELECT * FROM structure_ranks WHERE rank > ?";

// Fetch all rows from the result set and store them in the array
$result = $conn->execute_query($sql, [$rank])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// SQL query using a variable
$sql = "INSERT INTO structure_ranks (rank, whatever, foo, bar) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

// A separate Insert method is indeed of no use
$conn->execute_query($sql, [$rank, $whatever, $foo, $bar]);
```

The only place for improvement I can see here is the syntax for getting all rows which is indeed rather verbose. So in your place I would focus this custom class on several fetch methods that return different types of array, such as

- `fetchRows()` just an alias for fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
- `fetchList()` to get values of single columns
- `fetchIndexed($index = 'id')` that implements the fetching loop from "as opposed" section
- `fetchDict()` which combines the above two, taking the first selected column for index and the second for value
- `fetchCell()` just an alias for native mysqli's fetch_column()
- `fetch()` just an alias for fetch_assoc()

Given you showed some interest in the review, I will add some. A quite good example is

```
try
    {
        if (!isset($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname)
            || empty($this->host)
            || empty($this->username)
            || empty($this->password)
            || empty($this->dbname))
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Connection string expects values for ['host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname']");
        }
    }
    catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e)
    {
        error_log("Missing Configuration Index: {$e}");
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

which, taken by itself, without any context, can be rewritten to

```
if (!$this->host || !$this->username || !$this->password || !$this->dbname) {
    $e = new \InvalidArgumentException("Connection string expects values for ['host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname']");
    error_log("Missing Configuration Index: {$e}");
    throw $e;
}
```

because

- `isset()` being useless for checking properties that deliberately exist, being defined in the class definition. Here is another [live demonstration](https://3v4l.org/bBpGN): even without `isset()` this code behaves exactly the same.
- `empty()` being twice useless as it is checking the existence of the existing variable that was already checked for existence by isset
- `try` being useless because it is used here not on purpose, but for the control flow, which is already done by `if` statement.

Yet, taking into account the actual context, this code block should be just removed altogether. Because, again, in case your credentials are incorrect, mysql will readily provide the error message telling you that. Besides, this pesky verification just gets in the way. Why can't I provide an empty parameter - or null, to use the default value?

Another vivid example is

```
    catch (ConnectionException $e)
    {
        error_log("Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
    catch (DatabaseException $e)
    {
        error_log("Database Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        error_log("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
```

As we can see, the code is basically duplicated here three times, only to add textual remarks that are rather superfluous. Why not to leave just the `Exception` case (or `Throwable` for that matter)?

Yet again, catching exception only to log it makes little sense. PHP already can log errors. Why not to just leave this exception alone and let PHP log it *just like any other error*?

> *I honestly, genuinely don't understand, why database errors should receive some special treatment or a supplementary textual remark. Like, **never in my life** I've seen anyone wrapping a `require` call in a `try-catch` that simply adds "Filesystem error:" and throws the exception again. But for some reason many people consider essential to add a try catch for the database call*.

A rather small issue: here, the `else` clause is superfuluous

```
        {
        else
        {
            return $this->conn;
        }
```

and usually written as

```
        }
        return $this->conn;
```

Finally, like I said in the comments, the `if` statement here is  superfluous too.

```
        if ($this->conn->connect_error)
        {
            throw new ConnectionException(
              $this->conn->connect_error
            );
        }
```

Like it is said in the article I linked above, you can always configure mysqli to throw exceptions by itself, which renders all such conditions also useless.

Comment: The Config class is designed so that a developer can easily switch between database sources. You call it "cargo cult" code, but my way makes it easy to compare data from two databases. It also aims to alert the developer if the source he provided is accurate, and why not. Not sure how you can state I wrote it without needing it when I wrote it *because* it was needed.

Comment: Your code also has no error handling. If we did a `fetch_all` on a bad SQL query, we get a fatal error. The functions account for error handling and other things. In the end, this 'simple' code isn't thinking about the future

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is "database source"? Got an example of such "easy switching"? You never mention it in your question and it is not clearly evident from the code. What is the actual use case that proved such a *need*?

Comment: That's a bit peculiar way for asking but thank you anyway. Actually my code does have all the error handling (or, rather, reporting) it needs. And there is much more thinking about future than you can think of. Regarding error reporting, there is a simple configuration option that tells mysqli to report query errors (which is on by default in the current PHP version of 8.2). Which makes all the elaborate error reporting code in your class just useless. Another example of useless code I added to the answer.

Comment: I mean, reading the code would tell you what it does. But a simple example is switching between the development environment database and the production environment. As I said before, what if I simply want to use two databases without developing an API? This is a way to do that.

Comment: And no, your code does not provide the proper error handling. Let's say that you run a query for people with a rank above 11. If there are no people, somewhere along the way I get a "Cannot xxx on Null" result with your code. When I simply want the code to do nothing, aka return false.

Comment: @Bellator so this code simply does nothing aka returns false :)

Comment: I encourage you to actually test this code, as not to embarrass your self by making such unfounded statements :) there is an [online playground](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php82/2bd2db7da5945362dc4f4e545490304c/) where you can test the code and see how it works.

Comment: "switching between the development environment database and the production environment" is not a subject of the code it all.  you just have different database.ini in these environments. As simple as that.

Comment: The code checks for a connection string. If one does not exist, it then pulls a default one from database.ini. So I could pass any connection array to the function that I needed to. This is the place where error handling is necessary, to verify all the proper indexes are in that array. In the end, you have not reviewed my code, you have removed necessary functionality due to pre-existing personal opinions you have. Read the code.

Comment: @Bellator well, that's another quite elaborate solution to the problem that doesn't need any solution at all :) You can always supply your array directly into new mysqli. And again, even here your logic failed :) if you want to check if array elements are set, then you need to check this exact array. Instead, you are assigning values to some other variables using default values for absent elements and *then* check if those are set. This is the definition of a cargo cult code. but I see, as I anticipated, you aren't really interested in a code review, so we will conclude for now.

Comment: Yet the offer persists. Ping me any time when you will have a mind for a review

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks. I’m interested in a code review from someone who can actually read code. Because you’re constantly misinterpreting the code, and you do not ask for clarification. You’re clearly an old head who’s stubborn to admit you can be wrong, just like everyone else.

Comment: :))) Just get to this review when you overcome your petty grudge. There's a whole lot of new information for you.

Comment: You are the one with the petty grudge. You begin by stating your personal opinions and didn't actually read the code.

Comment: Wonder how I can notice useless parts of your code explained in my answer without reading the code :)

Comment: Once again stating your OPINION. Such a weird take to claim code is useless when it obviously has a use.

Comment: I have objections. Let's see who actually cannot read here. I admit, I used wrong words that made you upset and I beg my pardon for it. We all love our code and least we are inclined to listen when someone calls it useless. But, if you manage to overcome that grudge, try to actually read past these words. Many parts of your code are *technically*, well, call it "*dead*". In the meaning it never runs. So it's anything but "opinion". It's rather deep understanding of the code. Not only I can *read* PHP code but also evaluate it in my head and predict the outcome.

Comment: Take the very first example I added to my answer. The code inside condition on the line 32 of config.php  is a *dead code.* Which means it never runs. Here, [I made a standalone working excerpt](https://3v4l.org/ukkMu). You are expecting this code to throw \InvalidArgumentException with custom error message in case $mysqli is not null and not mysqli. But, as you can see, it's another error, which is thrown even before the execution reached that condition. Which makes this condition *useless*, no matter if like it or not.

Comment: Now, the next example. the `!isset($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname)` is definitely not "dead" but effectively useless. If you remove it, your code will behave exactly the same. Here, again, a [working excerpt](https://3v4l.org/bBpGN). You are expecting this code to throw an exception, if any of required variables are not set or "empty". Given empty() already covers the "not set" case, it makes isset *useless* here: as you can *read* in the output section, the exception is thrown all the same.

Comment: Look at that, you've actually found something wrong with the code. After weeks of opinions and incorrectly pointing out things. What'd you do, run it through ChatGPT for help with how to read code? And still, with the things you've found wrong, it's not with the logic or usability of the code as you were trying to point out before. It's random small oversight things.

Comment: It's not after weeks. All this stuff was there from the beginning. All I did is added live demonstrations. Which show that it's exactly *logic* of your code which is wrong :) And I can keep adding such demonstrations to prove every single line of my answer. But obviously, you just you don't *want* to listen to any criticism, flattering yourself with the idea that your code is perfect and what could be improved is only a "coding style". What a joke :)

Comment: Actually, the logic of the code isn't wrong. Those two things you mentioned were an oversight, yes. But the logic works fine.

Comment: That's a bit too much for the oversight, given *most* of your code can be removed this way. For example, you don't understand how mysqli works, and elaborately recreate its functionality, writing LOTS of code only to perform a task that mysqli already does by itself. "Weeks ago" I [offered you a live demonstration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285489/?noredirect=1#comment569832_286230), that does **exactly the same** as your code, but with native mysqli only, without using your class. But you just brushed it off. Why did you even ask for a review if you don't even read it?

Comment: All right, it seems you tend to simply brush off a code that you don't understand. And each line needs to be explained to you. Here you go: your function Query() being useless because mysqli already has execute_query(). Your function Rows() being rather useless, as mysqli already has fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) which is only slightly longer to call (which I admitted in my review). trigger_error() is useless because mysqli already throws an Exception in case of error, as shown in the live demo above.

Comment: My functions are there to implement parameterized queries. You're once again showing YOU don't understand code.

Comment: If you take a look at the review above, you will see an example that's using *parameterized queries*. Look at yourself. You are badmouthing a person who is trying to help, calling me an impostor, an illiterate. I am working with mysqli for more than ten years, wrote many articles on it that helped millions. And you are doing first feeble steps using this extension but consider yourself a genius and everyone else an idiot. What a shame.

Comment: Are you serious…? Are you saying you expect me to not utilize functions and to rewrite the 8 lines of code to parametize queries each time? What’s wrong with you pal

Comment: Why you're making a fool of yourself making such statements? Where do you find those  "8 lines of code" my review?

Comment: Admittedly, that's a new function and if your PHP version is outdated, it may not be supported. But to recreate its functionality, you need only a [few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76934685/285587), not a hundred that you wrote.

Comment: I already proved you incompetent, by disproving every ridiculous statement you made, such as "I get a "Cannot xxx on Null" result with your code" or those "8 lines of code". I already demonstrated that most of the code you wrote is just useless or the same result can be achieved with less code. But still somehow it's me with whom something is wrong. I never seen a person who is shown that their ideas are all wrong if not ridiculous, but who is unable to admit it, blaming everyone else. What a shame of a human being.